# Recyclerview not finding ID of element in Layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My `RecyclerView` is not able to find element's `id`. I tried to use `findViewById` but it is not working as my app gets crashed.

This is my Custom Adapter - `MyRecyclerAdapter.kt`:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapter(
    private var notiList : ArrayList<NotificationClass>) :RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>(){

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
    return RecyclerViewHolder(itemView)}

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Problem Arise here
    holder.itemView.titleView.text = notiList[position].title }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int = notiList.size

   class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

This is my item's Layout - `item_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:elevation="30dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semibold"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Markdown has semantic meaning; don't make up your own use cases, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the `ViewHolder` for your RecyclerView. It should be like below:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapter(
    private var notiList : ArrayList<NotificationClass>) :RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>(){
    
    // Define below ViewHolder
    internal inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
      var titleView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.titleView)
      var descView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.descView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
    return RecyclerViewHolder(itemView)}

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Problem Arise here
    holder.itemView.titleView.text = notiList[position].title }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int = notiList.size

   class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to access from `android.R`. Rather, try something like this:

```
CategoryAdapterHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
.inflate(com.example.secondhand.R.layout.category_list, parent, false))
```